# <News:somethinng>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

Here from my template I am getting the list of strings with `getlist` in a view. I want to assign these list in my `ManyToMany` field.I am getting the selected multiple list in my view and it is also creating the reporter object from these list which is fine.

Now I want to assign these only selected multiple options in my many to many field.

How can I do it here? I get this error while saving the form

```
 "<News:somethinng>" needs to have a value for field "id" before this many-to-many relationship can be used.
```

views

```
class NewsCreateVView(View):
    template_name = 'add_news.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = CreateNewsForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = CreateNewsForm(request.POST)
        reporters = request.POST.getlist('reporter')
        if form.is_valid():
            news = form.save(commit=False)
            for reporter in reporters:
                obj = Reporter.objects.create(name=reporter)
                news.reporter.add(obj.pk)
            news.save()
            return redirect('list_news')
```

models

```
class Reporter(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
   created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)

class News(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    reporter = models.ManyToManyField(Reporter, related_name='reporters')
```

template

```
<select class="form-control" name="reporter" multiple="multiple">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As the error says, `news` first needs to be saved in order to have a primary key, so:

```
class NewsCreateVView(View):
    template_name = 'add_news.html'

    def get(self, request):
        form = CreateNewsForm()
        return render(request, self.template_name, {'form': form})

    def post(self, request, **kwargs):
        form = CreateNewsForm(request.POST)
        reporters = request.POST.getlist('reporter')
        if form.is_valid():
            news = form.save()
            pks = [Reporter.objects.create(name=reporter).pk
                   for reporter in reporters]
            news.reporters.add(*pks)
            return redirect('list_news')
```